# "Choice of" usage

Tags: prepositional-phrases, complementation

I read a sentence in [scientificamerican](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode/hacked-e-cigs-may-get-around-regulations1/)

> it’s enough to make you question one company’s choice of renowned vaccine expert Jenny McCarthy to be their e-cigarette celebrity pitchwoman.

It's a little weird to me since in my opinion the noun after choice of should not be specific. For example

> My **choice of gun** to shoot zombies is AK47.

It can be career, food, but not Jenny McCarthy.

Can anyone explained that sentence or correct my understanding?

Comment: I *really* suggest you use [Longmans Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/choice_1) and consult Definition 3: Choice of: the person or thing someone chooses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:
The quoted sentence is fine: the choice of which constituent to express with an *of* phrase is determined by rhetorical purpose.

LONGER ANSWER:
It may help you to think of *choice* as being a noun form of the verb *choose*. The ordinary use of *choose* has a Subject (SUBJ) and two complements, a Direct Object (DO) and an object-modifying complement (OC). The OC is cast as a phrase  headed by either *as* or *to be*.<sup>†</sup>

> A<sup>SUBJ</sup> chooses X<sup>DO</sup> [to be Y]<sup>OC</sup> *or*
>   A<sup>SUBJ</sup> chooses X<sup>DO</sup> [as Y]<sup>OC</sup>.

So the two sentences you give may be understood thus:

> [The company]<sup>SUBJ</sup> chooses [Jenny McCarthy]<sup>DO</sup> [to be their spokesman]<sup>OC</sup>
>   I<sup>SUBJ</sup> choose [the AK47]<sup>DO</sup> [as a gun to shoot zombies]<sup>OC</sup>.

Note, however, that both complements are not required; one may be inferred from context. If only the OC is present, it is ‘recast’ as the DO:

> The company chooses Jenny McCarthy.
>   I choose a gun to shoot zombies.

Consequently, when you recast the verb *choose* as the noun *choice*, any of these three ‘variables’ may be expressed with *of*. Which you choose depends on what (if anything) you want to do with the third term, and where you want to put the focus; when you have decided those things, you manipulate the pieces to achieve the result you want.

In your sentence, for instance, your focus is on *the AK47*, which you want to put in the ‘new information’ position:

> My choice is the AK47.

Consequently, you use the *of* phrase to cast the function as a modifier of *choice*:

> My choice of gun to shoot zombies ...

But in other circumstances you might want to put the focus on the function:

> My choice of the AK47 is as a gun to shoot zombies. (If I were hunting squirrel I would pick another weapon.)

And if I were writing this I might want to ignore the function and put the focus on *you*:

> This AK47 is the choice of CYC. (***I*** would have picked a Pancor Jackhammer.)

---

<sup>†</sup>The syntax is considerably more complex with *to be*, but since that is not relevant here I will ignore it.